# Save locations in Google Calendar for places you use frequently

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar, is there a way to save locations for places you name in the where field?

For example, if you make an entry in Google Calendar and put the location as "dentist office" could it somehow auto-populate the actual address of the dentist office?